# Unable to run an application on other device after development

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently I developed an android application for the first time and I was looking forward to transfer it in the form of apk to another device.  But unfortunately, I was not able to run it there. Can someone guide me on how can I transfer an application to another device without publishing it to playstore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 

At Android studio, go to Build -> Build Bundle(s) / APK(s) -> Build APK(s).

This is the way to get an apk from android studio. After you made an apk file from Window, you can mail it to your phone or any device.

2.
You can connect your device to the computer, and click Run 'app', which is green triangle.

This is the two way that you can run your application on the Samsung and Android based device.
Also, you can go into the developer mode in your Samsung device.

Answer (score 0):

**On non-Samsung devices:**

- Go to your phone’s Settings.
- Go to Security & privacy > More settings.
- Tap on Install apps from external sources.
- Select the browser (e.g., Chrome or Firefox) you want to download the APK files from.
- Toggle Allow app installs on.

**On Samsung devices:**

- Go to your phone’s Settings.
- Go to Biometrics and security > Install unknown apps.
- Select the browser (e.g., Chrome or Firefox) you want to download the APK files from.
- Toggle Allow app installs on.

After allowing chrome, drive, file manager, etc. just browse/download the file from it and install.

Answer (score 0):

depending upon the app developing software you used the process may be different.
The two most common one of them is android studio and visual studio:

Android Studio:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run
Visual studio:
Right-click at your Android project: open ‘Properties’ tab. Be sure that selected drop down is ‘Release’, not ‘Debug’.
Click ‘Build’ -> ‘Clean solution’:
3. Then click ‘Build’ -> ‘Rebuild’.

4. Create the package: